# If cells in range not in date format dd-mm-yy then prohibit saving the file

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, save

I have an Excel worksheet where users paste their data.

To save (save, save as or crtl+s) the data has to conform to conditions.

If the non-empty cells in the first column do not have the date format dd-mm-yy, I want to prohibit saving the file.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
   
Dim cell As Range
   
For Each cell In Range("A2:A1048576")         
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        If IsDate(cell) Then                 
            If Not Format(cell, "dd-mm-yy") = cell Then
                MsgBox "Opslaan van dit bestand is niet mogelijk omdat niet alle data correct is ingevuld.", vbCritical
                Cancel = True
                Exit Sub                 
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Opslaan van dit bestand is niet mogelijk omdat niet alle data correct is ingevuld.", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next cell
               
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How the date is displayed on the sheet can be set by the script, no need for a check. Or are you really wanting to check for valid dates ?

Comment: @CDP1802 is correct just forced the format beforesave `Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yy"`

Comment: Checking whether it was in the right format seemed easier else you have to wright a code for every type of data input (string, date, etc) but maybe i'm wrong. Also I have multiple columns. I want the code to check the following too: column 2 is a number between 1 and 999,  column 3 is a number between 1000 and 9999, column 4 contains two letters (e.g. AA), column 5 contains text, column 6 contains a number with one decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Is there only one tab? You've not qualified any ranges.

Try the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Const formatting As String = "dd-mm-yy"
    Const MsgError As String = "Opslaan van dit bestand is niet mogelijk omdat niet alle data correct is ingevuld."
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change this to the correct tab name or use ActiveSheet
        For Each cell In Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:A"))
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) And cell.Row <> 1 Then
                If IsDate(cell) Then
                    If Not Format(cell, formatting) = cell.Text Then
                        MsgBox MsgError, vbCritical
                        Cancel = True
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox MsgError, vbCritical
                    Cancel = True
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

The main changes are:

- Added UsedRange into the mix so it doesn't read the entirety of column A if it's not all used.
- Added Worksheet reference of Sheet1 - change as needed.
- Changed `= cell` to `= cell.text` which will return the value
  *as displayed in the cell* - which for dates is quite different to the
  actual value stored.
- Used some Const variables to make it easier to change if required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I thought i did set the range: For Each cell In Range("A2:A1048576"). Is this wrong?  Your way is better of course. But to learn from the mistakes, i wondered if it was wrong.                                                      There is only one tab yes. I'm going to try you code and i'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Nothing particularly wrong with that method - but it could cause problems if the program was run on a differently sized worksheet - i.e. a shorter xls file or perhaps in the future there will be even more rows available.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim cell As Range, ws As Worksheet, n As Long
   
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Columns("A:F").Cells
    
        'column 1 is date dd-mm-yy
        'column 2 is a number between 1 and 999,
        'column 3 is a number between 1000 and 9999,
        'column 4 contains two letters (e.g. AA),
        'column 5 contains text,
        'column 6 contains a number with one decimal.
    
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            Select Case cell.Column
                Case 1
                    If IsDate(cell) Then
                        cell.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yy"
                    Else
                        Cancel = True
                    End If
                Case 2
                    If cell.Value < 1 Or cell.Value > 999 Then
                        Cancel = True
                    End If
                Case 3
                    If cell.Value < 1000 Or cell.Value > 9999 Then
                        Cancel = True
                    End If
                Case 4
                    If Not cell.Value Like "*[A-Z][A-Z]*" Then
                        Cancel = True
                    End If
                Case 5
                    If Not cell.Value Like "*[A-Za-z]*" Then
                        Cancel = True
                    End If
                Case 6
                    If IsNumeric(cell.Value) And cell.Text Like "*.#" Then
                    Else
                        Cancel = True
                    End If
            End Select
            
            If Cancel Then
                n = n + 1
                'cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow ' test
                Cancel = False
            End If
        End If
   
    Next
    If n > 0 Then
         MsgBox "Opslaan van dit bestand is niet mogelijk omdat " & _
         "niet alle data correct is ingevuld.", vbCritical, n & " cells incorrect"
         Cancel = True
    End If
               
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! A question. Why does the following part has a cancel=false in it?

    If Cancel Then
       n = n + 1
       'cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow ' test
       Cancel = False
    End If

Because it counts the number of occurred cancels?

Comment: @babs it counts the number of cells that fail checks for the if n>0 block at the  Sub exit.